# Project is already on GitHub

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I tried to share my Java project via IntelliJ to GitHub. In this case I choose `VSC/Import into Version Control/Share Project on GitHub` and go through few windows. But at one where I should provide repository name and its description I cancel the operation. But the repository was shared... So I removed it via GitHub webpage. I tried share it one more time via IntelliJ, but I get `Project is already on GitHub` info. How can I solve this situation?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your project physical location and find .git folder(hidden, right click open in new window, if you have problems on mac). You might need figure out how to show hidden folders/files on your OS.
2. Find file "config"
3. Delete section(s) [remote "name"]
4. Try to share again
5. Enjoy )

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Then manage remotes

[image]

then delete here

Comment: @NewbieAF: These aren't just links. They are links to images. The author simply doesn't have the privileges necessary to embed the images. That's quite a bit different than just a link to another web page.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I see. The images weren't visible in review (it was just two links).

Comment: @NewbieAF: Yes. I edited the answer to embed the links during my review. Generally, that's a good practice—assuming, of course, the images are relevant, not blocks of code, and the answer is still a legitimate attempt to answer the question (as was the case here).